# Build definition to deploy to remote private server

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have recently learned about Visual Studio Team Services continuous integration and I would like to add a build-step in my build definition to deploy the website files to a remote development server. Similar to what the Azure Web App Deployment does but to my own hosting server. I have figured a way to do this using the Windows Machine File Copy or using a custom PowerShell script, but the problem is, I have to open up my server's ports for SMB to get this working.

Is there a list of IP addresses I could white-list that Visual Studio Team Services uses? From 4 build tests, I managed to get four IP addresses:
- 13.80.13.96
- 40.114.244.33
- 40.114.240.144
- 104.47.152.33

This does not look very promising.

I may be complicating things, so is there a better way of doing this securely?

Answer (score 0):

SMB shouldn't factor into it. The [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) uses WinRM. For security, make sure you use HTTPS and valid certificates in place.

There is no list of valid IP address ranges for the hosted build agents that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a "Command Line" task to use MSDeploy to publish the website if your private server run with IIS. (Set the "Tool" area in "Command Line" task to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" if you are using Hosted Build Agent.)

Some reference links:

[Using MSDeploy to publish your site](http://blog.winhost.com/using-msdeploy-to-publish-your-site/)

[(MSDeploy) Deploying Contents of a Folder to a Remote IIS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885454/msdeploy-deploying-contents-of-a-folder-to-a-remote-iis-server)