# MSDeploy - Synchronizing to a remote folder using a manifest

Tags: directory, manifest, msdeploy

I have seen many answers to questions that appear to be exactly what I am looking for, such as [(MSDeploy) Deploying Contents of a Folder to a Remote IIS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885454/msdeploy-deploying-contents-of-a-folder-to-a-remote-iis-server), but these answers don't do what I need.  I don't want to install the MSDeploy agent on the remote computer, or specify credentials to use.

This command does exactly what I want, but does not use a manifest, so my install script would need to know the destination for each package.

```
MSDeploy -verb:sync -disableRule:BackupRule ^
         -source:package=pkg.zip ^
         -dest:contentPath=\\server\share\path
```

If I use a manifest for the dest, and that manifest specifies a single contentPath (or dirPath) provider, such as:

```
<sitemanifest>
  <contentPath path="\\server\share\path">
</sitemanifest>
```

I get an error that the source (package) is not compatible with the dest (contentPath).

I've tried variations, such as using a full local path in the manifest and ",computerName=server" after the dest specification.  This one wants the MSDeploy agent on the remote computer and for me to specify credentials.

I can't find any detailed documentation on the use of MSDeploy, only a myriad of examples that don't fit my needs.

I think the first example of what I tried above is likely the correct path, but I need to figure out how to package the source or build the manifest to make the two compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the destination manifest doesn't match the manifest used to create the package or the package was not created from a manifest.  The manifests have to match.  If you let VS/MSBuild create the package you can open it with a zip utility and find the manifest file (the file is named archive.xml) that was used to create the package.  Make a copy of that file and adjust the values for each manifest line as appropriate.

Here are a couple of blog posts that should help.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

This one is about creating a package manually.  If you created the package manually you probably need to change to create it from a source manifest.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/23/deploy-an-asp-net-website-not-web-application-with-msdeploy/