# Jenkins deploy artifact on same server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkins Pipeline or group of itens to help me create a custom CI/CD for my projects and right now i'm stuck at the deploy part, i want to deploy on the same server that my jenkins is running (Windows Server/IIS). I would also like to know how to deploy to another server (Windows Server/IIS), this second one would be my production env.

I have managed to clone, build and archive using two approaches with Jenkins:

- Pipelines
  I have managed to create a pipeline that will clone my project, execute my build and then archive the artifacts from my build. The problem is, how do i deploy the artifact now?

This is my pipeline script

```
node {
   stage('git clone') {
      // Get some code from a GitHub repository
      git 'my-git-url'
   }
   stage('npm install') {
      bat label: 'npm install',
      script: '''cd app
        npm install'''
   }
   stage('gulp install') {
      bat label: 'gulp install',
      script: '''cd app
      npm i gulp'''
   }
   stage('gulp production') {
      bat label: 'gulp production',
      script: '''cd app
      gulp production'''
   }
   stage('create artifact') {
      archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'app/dist/**',
      onlyIfSuccessful: true
   }
}
```

- Freestyle projects
  I have managed to create a project that will build and then archive the artifact using `Execute shell` build step and the `Archive the artifacts` post-build actions. How can i deploy the artifact using this approach? On this case i'm trying  to trigger a second freestyle project to execute the deploy.

Comment: What is the result of your build commands? A bunch of css, fonts, js and index.html?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, right now i'm only building the frontend, i will also need to later build my .net api and send some of it's files over.

Comment: Ok. Do you need to deploy the css, fonts, js and index.html in your IIS using Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned both servers use IIS

Comment: In order to serve your static assets (css, fonts, js and index.html), you just need a basic http server like : apache, nginx, nodejs, etc. Are you able to config this on your IIS server : https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-hosting/how-to-build-static-website-iis/ ??

Comment: @JRichardsz i think there is a misunderstand on what i need: i already know how to configure an IIS to host my applications, what i need is to publish those assets from one server to another using jenkins pipeline (preferably) or freestyle project

Answer (score 0):

According to your question : **"I want to deploy on the same server that my jenkins is running (Windows Server/IIS)" ..** and comments I will suggest some approaches.

## Windows

Use windows as operative system for production environments is not recommended. Linux is the only and the best choice.

## IIS

I don't recommed IIS to deploys static assets. You need something more light and scalable. You could use :

- nodejs with pm2 (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)
- nginx (https://medium.com/@jgefroh/a-guide-to-using-nginx-for-static-websites-d96a9d034940)
- apache (http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files)
- docker

## Deploy on IIS

Deploy static assets on IIS is just **copy and paste** the files on some folder and point IIS configurations to that folder:

- https://www.atlantic.net/hipaa-compliant-hosting/how-to-build-static-website-iis/

## Basic deploy on IIS using Jenkins

After your build commands, you just need to **copy** the build results (css.js.html.etc) and **paste** to some folder like **c://webapps/my-app** (pre-configured in IIS).

You can do this using a simple shell execution in **free style project** or pipeline script like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53159387/3957754

You could use this approach to deploy your static assets on the same server that your jenkins is running.

## Advanced deploy on IIS using Jenkins

Microsoft has a tool called **MSDeploy**. Basically is a command line tool to deploy apps on **remote** IIS:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath="" -dest:contentPath=""
```

More details here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032030/3957754

**Note:** [You can't run MS deploy commands that talk to the MSDeploy service on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38997178/3957754)

## Jenkins Agent

Jenkins agent is an application that runs on a remote server, not where jenkins master node runs.

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Your master jenkins could use an agent in the remote or localhost IIS and execute jenkins jobs with **copy and paste** approach.